# Why is lattice-based cryptography believed to be hard to solve for quantum computers?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, cryptography

Lattice-based cryptography is said to be the main contender for a post-quantum cryptography framework. It's thought that instead of having to switch everything over to QKD, post-quantum algorithms can instead be used that use a harder problem to solve than the typical RSA.

But is there any general understanding why lattice-based cryptography is actually a hard problem for quantum computers? [An answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/50856/why-is-lattice-based-cryptography-believed-to-be-hard-against-quantum-computer) from the cryptography stack exchange suggests that this is simply because an algorithm hasn't been developed for it yet. This hardly seems like reassurance. Of course a new problem will take time for people to develop a quantum algorithm for.

Is there something about the lattice based method that makes it less susceptible to quantum computers? For example, I believe parallelization to often be a important factor to a problem being speedy on a quantum computer. Perhaps lattice-based methods are less parallelizable?

Comment: A solution to the [Hidden Subgroup Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_subgroup_problem) for dihedral groups would crack many lattice-based crypto systems, so another question is why could the HSP for dihedral groups not be in BQP while for abelian groups it most certainly is.  I think it has something to do with characters of irreps being too close to each other... <mumble mumble don't understand>